# Use mesh tool in Illustrator to create single vector objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes

Does anybody know if it is possible to use the mesh tool for creating multiple vector objects?

For example, I have a rectangle and add a mesh with the mesh tool:

[image]

Now, I want to use the "mesh lines" as a kind of "cutting lines" to split the rectangle into multiple objects with the form of the meshed grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's no way to turn the mesh lines in to actual paths.

You could work around it by recreating the grid and warping it with the mesh. Note, this only really works if you're working with a rectangular mesh where only the inner points have been manipulated though...

1. Once you have your mesh how you want it, lock the mesh layer  and turn on outline view (*View → Outline* or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>).
2. Draw a rectangle perfectly over your mesh.
3. Count the number of rows and columns in your mesh. Select the rectangle above your mesh and go to *Object → Path → Split into Grid...* Set the same number of rows and columns (with no gutter).

   You should have something like this:

   [image]
4. Use the Direct Selection Tool to select entire rows and columns of anchor points and align every row and column with your mesh.

   You should have something like this:

   [image]
5. Unlock the mesh layer, move the mesh above the grid, select both grid and mesh then go to *Object → Envelope Distort → Make with Top Object*

   [image]
6. Turn off outline mode (I've added a stroke to the grid so you can see the result)

   [image]
7. Expand. Done.